# how can i send an entire class from one process to another avoiding serialization?

Tags: c++, unix, protocols

During my free-time programming i have encountered a problem.

Let us say, there is a large program **A.cpp** written by me and there is file **B.cpp** generated by bison+flex.
During my run of program A i want to execute a parser (B) and then return a *very complex* object to A.

Are there any ways to perform this task, **other** then serializing the class into the pipe?

**UPD** The problem with serialization is simple: i just can't link boost libraries with my .cpp.

I have tried to reinstall libboost-dev 1.46, but linker keeps shouting, that references aren't met.

My code looks like this:

```
A.cpp
class blah {
  void read () {
      yyparse();
      arch >> *this;
  }
}

B.cpp:
int main() {
   yyparse(); // yacc parsing
   arch << result;
}
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
bison -d -v reader.y
cp reader.tab.c bison.c
cmp -s reader.tab.h tok.h || cp reader.tab.h tok.h
g++ -O2 -std=c++0x -w -l boost_serialization  -c bison.c -o bison.o
flex -d reader.lex
cp lex.yy.c lex.c
g++ -O2 -std=c++0x -w -l boost_serialization  -c lex.c -o lex.o
g++ -O2 -std=c++0x -w -l boost_serialization  -c reader.cpp -o main.o
g++ -O2 -std=c++0x -w -l boost_serialization  bison.o lex.o main.o -o reader -lfl
```

Comment: "ladies and..."?  Separately, do you mean "very complex *object* to A"?  Classes have no runtime representation.  Perhaps you could put the object in shared memory, or a file and memory map it...?  Or embed the parser in program A so it can generate the class in the same memory space.

Comment: CORBA? COM? DCOM? Depends on the technology you want to use

Comment: Any of those will do internal serialization when passing across process boundaries.

Comment: So, how can i put an object into the shared memory?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - COM objects are not serialized

Comment: I'm a little intrigued about what is coming out of this parser that is runtime usable to the cpp program.

Comment: If the contents of the object are not self contained, ie would not fit in a single memory block (such as containing pointers to other memory blocks), then it would not work with shared memory unless it is serialized into the shared memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - There aren't pointer outside the object, but the inner structure is very complex indeed. So, how can i put an object into the shared memory?

Comment: @marqueewinq - Why not bite the bullet and serialize it?

Comment: Yes you can put the object in shared memory, but the process you're describing is called serialization.  But you haven't told us: *what is the problem with serialization*?

Comment: _'So, how can i put an object into the shared memory?'_ If you mean **complex object** you'll need to put it there being consistent in itself. Using "shared" pointers instead of offsets might not give the right results. I'd say serialization might be the more flexible choice, even for mem-mapped space (separate transport from protocol formats!!).

Comment: @Duck - This work is my end-term work, connecting a problem in linguistics to physx

Comment: @EdHeal - I have been sitting in front of the monitor for a long time fighting with a boost::serialize without any particular positive outcome -- so i started to think in another way.

Comment: @marqueewinq - Why not get to grips with a couple of tutorials first before tackling you particular problem?

Comment: @EdHeal - You are absolutely right; however, when i have been trying to compile tutorials on my machine, there is a miraculous problem with linker. I have been serfing this site on the topic, but nothing seems to help. Ok, i understood, that serialization is inevitable, so my quest continues. )

Comment: @marqueewinq - You can serialise objects without requiring boost. Just convert the data in the object into a string.

Comment: @EdHeal - It tooks much more space and time to write/read a data in such form -- but thanks, i will solve my problem in this way.

Comment: @EdHeal - You know, it will take much of ''my'' time. :(

Comment: How are `A.cpp` and `B.cpp` programs?  Those sound like source files, not programs...

Comment: @Yakk - Ofc they are source files. Haven't you encountered the people who call the program's code a 'program' by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data has to pass across process boundaries then you cannot avoid serializing the data into a transportable format.  Especially if the data contains any pointers/references to other memory, or even to its own internal members, since those pointers/references would not be valid in another process's address space.

Comment: Actually shared memory does require serialization.

Comment: Well imagine that your object contains a pointer or reference.

Comment: The contents of the object would have to be copied into the shared memory, and that may require serialization, depending on the layout and contents of the object. For example, strings would have to be serialized, unless the object is used fixed-length arrays for character data.

Comment: In other words, if your object is already in serialized format, then you don't need serialization!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Aggreed: **"Marshalling"** is just a stupid obfuscating term (maybe including some additional behavior contracts) above that general serialization constraints ...